# SQL into LinQ Stement involving SUM()

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I am having trouble converting the SQL code below into LinQ method syntax

```
select top(5) MerchantUserId,sum(TotalAmount) as TotalAmount from OrderTransaction 
group by MerchantUserId 
order by TotalAmount desc
```

I have tried but I just cant get the LinQ to accommodate the function SUM

```
var list = _ApplicationDbContext.OrderTransaction
          .Where(x => x.Status != 0)
          .GroupBy(x => x.MerchantUserId)
          .Select(x => new DashboardMerchantStoreRankingByOrderAmount { MerchantUserId = x.Key })
          .OrderByDescending(x => x.TotalAmount)
          .Take(5)
          .ToList();
```

Below are the class for storing an individual record

```
public class DashboardMerchantStoreRankingByOrderAmount
{
    public Guid MerchantUserId { get; set; }
    public double TotalAmount { get; set; }
    
}
```

Essentially, I want to retrieve the top 5 best performing merchant based on their order amount.

Answer (score 1):

The following query implements exactly the sql query.

```
var query = _ApplicationDbContext.OrderTransaction.Where(x => x.Status != 0)
  .GroupBy(a => a.MerchantUserId)
  .Select(group =>
     new DashboardMerchantStoreRankingByOrderAmount
     {
         MerchantUserId = group.Key,
         TotalAmount = group.OrderByDescending(a => a.TotalAmount).Select(a => a.TotalAmount).Take(5).Sum()
     }).ToList();
```